# Cannot make copy arraylist in RecyclerView_Adapter constructor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a small problem with understanding how to copy `ArrayList`. There is my code:

```java
public class RecyclerView_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter.recyclerViewHolder>{
    private List<Item> list1;
    private List<Item> list2;
    
    // with constructor:
    public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, Arraylist<Item> list1){
        this.context = context;
        this.list1 = list1;
        this.list2 = new Arraylist<>(list1)
    }
}
```

It should copy list1 to list2 right?
When I use this code:

```
Log.i("TAG1", list1.toString());
Log.i("TAG2", list2.toString());
```

it returns

```
TAG1 : []
TAG2 : []
```

Later in another place (for example in viewholder)
same code returns:

```
TAG1: [com.example.something1290, com.example.something1267, com.example.something1298] (some data)
TAG2: [] // <-- still returns empty array why?
```

When I use this code, not in conctructor but at some other place then it returns the same data in both arrays.

So the question is:

why in constructor I cannot copy list1 to list 2 but I must to do this in different method?
**EDIT:**
It looks like:

```
// with constructor:
    public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, Arraylist<Item> list1){
        this.context = context;
        Log.i("TAG1", list1.toString());
        this.list1 = list1;
        this.list2 = new Arraylist<>(list1)
        // It can return an empty array like:
        TAG1 : []
    }
}
```

But In this case:

```
// with constructor:
    public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, Arraylist<Item> list1){
        this.context = context;
        this.list1 = list1;
        Log.i("TAG1", list1.toString());
        this.list2 = new Arraylist<>(list1)
        // It should return an array with data, but return empty array again
        TAG1 : []
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify: Are both ArrayLists empty in the constructor? Is list2 always empty when it's logged?

Comment: yes i think it should if list1 is not empty, copy anything with similar type is so easy, eg,int a; int b; a=5; b=a; (a is copied to b).

Comment: Yes, both arrays are empty. While I passing an array  to constructor,  Line this.list1 = list1; returns [] but in another method returns array with data. It looks like in constructor array1 returns as empty but in next method vieholder or onbindviewholder returns data where list2 still return [] empty tag. I thing problem is with array1 beacuse it copy to array2 empty data and then fill itselfs with data

Answer (score 0):

First that you are creating a list passing within another list. That will not make another copy and instead will insert another list within and not copying it . You can use methods like `ArrayList.clone()` or `ArrayList.addAll()` methods to achieve copying arraylist

```
// with constructor:
public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, Arraylist<Item> list1){
    this.context = context;
    Log.i("TAG1", list1.toString());
    this.list1 = list1;
    this.list2 = new Arraylist<>().addAll(list1) // or this.list2 = list1.clone();
    // It will return the contents of list1 copied to list2 array like:
    
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. 
I thought that copy of list should be sth like: `this.list2 = new Arraylist<>(list1);`
After tired your sollutuion android studio give me an error:
Incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to `List<Itemt>
           list2 = new ArrayList<>().addAll(list1);`
Clone give me:Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to `List<Item> ` in same line.
After I did  `list2 = (List<Item>) list1.clone(); ` a second array is still empty without error

Comment: Something intersting. In my OnResume method in MainActivity I have line: `new BackgroundTask(RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context, ArrayList<Item> datalist, DataBaseHelper dbhelper)` BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask. Then in doInBackground method(BackgroundTask.class). I put the data from sqldatabase to arraylist. This list is 
pass to RecyclerView_Adapter. At the end of OnResume method (MainActivity.class)  when I called Log.i("TAG" data_list.toString()); retruns empty tag [], but list is displayed properly. Maybe this why I have in RecyclerView_Adapter empty tag in constructor method

Comment: Second thing the last.  I think....:D
App returns an arrays with data, as if would like it. I added new Runnable method(with thread.sleep(1000 milis) in constructor. Earlier everything was made ok, but code goes forward not waiting for filling arrays with data.  In short it works but this sollution didn't gladden me, is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue. What worked for me is, I made a copy in my main activity class and passed both copies to the adapter.
something like:

In mainActivity:

```
ArrayList<Item> list1, list2;
list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list2 = new ArrayList<>();
//update list1 and right after that update list 2
list2.addAll(list1);

//pass both to adapter
recyclerView_Adapter = new RecyclerView_Adapter(this, list1, list2);
```

//inside adapter class define both variables
ArrayList list1, list2;

//inside adapter class constructor
public RecyclerView_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList list1, ArrayList list2){
this.context=context;
this.list1=list1;
this.list2=list2;
}